# How to initialiaze a unsigned byte array with a set of well known values in Java 7?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, byte

I want to initialize a byte array with unsigned byte values ranging from 0 to 255.

Here is how I did it:

```
int N = 256;
char[] tmp = new char[N];

for (char c = 0; c < N; c++) {
    tmp[c] = c;
}

byte[] table = new byte[N];
table = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").encode(CharBuffer.wrap(tmp)).array();

int i=1;
for(byte b : table) {
    System.out.format("%02X ",  b);
    if(i%10==0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    i++;
}
```

This produces:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 
1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 
3C 3D 3E 3F 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 60 61 62 63 
64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 
6E 6F 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 
78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F
```

Why is there a bunch of `3F` ? Why can't I get `80, 81 ...` after `7F` ?

**EDIT:**
Here is how I solve my issue

```
int N = 256;
byte[] table = new byte[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    table[i] = (byte) i;
}

int i=1;
for(byte b : table) {
    System.out.format("%02X ",  b);
    if(i%10==0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Outputs

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 
14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 
1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 
3C 3D 3E 3F 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 
5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 60 61 62 63 
64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 
6E 6F 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 
78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 80 81 
82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 8B 
8C 8D 8E 8F 90 91 92 93 94 95 
96 97 98 99 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F 
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 
AA AB AC AD AE AF B0 B1 B2 B3 
B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA BB BC BD 
BE BF C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 
C8 C9 CA CB CC CD CE CF D0 D1 
D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA DB 
DC DD DE DF E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 
E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF 
F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 
FA FB FC FD FE FF
```

Comment: Why are you going over chars? Why not just using bytes directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is there a bunch of 3F ? Why can't I get 80, 81 ... after 7F ?

Because your character array contains non-ASCII characters. `Charset.encode` is encoding those as 3F (ASCII for '?') to represent the fact that they're not in ASCII.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29):

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

It looks like you don't *really* want text data to start with, so I suggest you avoid it completely. Just populate the byte array directly:

```
byte[] table = new byte[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    table[i] = (byte) i;
}
```

Note that Java doesn't really *have* unsigned bytes - the above will end up with negative values for indexes 128-255... but they'll have the right *bits* set. You can treat them as unsigned values by masking them with 0xff:

```
int x = table[200] & 0xff; // Now x is 200
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest encoding is `ISO-8859-1`, it is doesn't appear you want encoding at all.

You can copy the characters one at a time

```
char[] tmp = new char[256];

for(char c = 0; c < tmp.length; c++)
    tmp[c] = c;

byte[] table = new byte[tmp.length];
for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    table[i] = (byte) tmp[i];

    System.out.format("%02X ",  table[i] & 0xff);
    if(i % 16 == 15) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

prints

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F 
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF 
B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA BB BC BD BE BF 
C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA CB CC CD CE CF 
D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA DB DC DD DE DF 
E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF 
F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FB FC FD FE FF
```

Comment: I would hesitate to recommend using any character encoding for this, as it looks to me like the OP doesn't *really* want characters in the first place... they're only using them as a means to an end.

Comment: This answer is interesting as it solves my issue by using a more appropriate `Charset`.

Comment: @Alex: Not really - it's not a "more appropriate" `Charset` because you aren't inherently dealing with text. It's a `Charset` which *happens* to map U+0000-U+00FF to bytes 0x00-0xff respectively... but it's still not (IMO) a good way to populate your byte array. Stay away from text, charsets, strings etc unless you're really trying to represent *text*.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int N = 256;

    byte[] table = new byte[N];
    for(int b = 1; b<N; b++){
        table[b] = (byte) b;
    }
```