# Java convert String of byte array to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I got a byte array sent from javascript by ajax looking like this:

```
"89,50,4e,47,0d,0a,1a,0a,00,00,00,0d,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,e4,08,06,00 ..."
```

I would like to convert this **string to a byte array**.
Pretty similar to this question, but using Java instead: [Convert String[] to byte[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531148/convert-string-to-byte-array)

Edit:
This seems to work - but not sure if i am doing it right

```
    String[] byteData ="89,50,4e,47,0d,0a,1a,0a,00,00,00,0d,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,e4,08,06,00";
    byte[] b = new byte[byteData.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
        BigInteger bla = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(byteData[i].trim(), 16) - 128);
        b[i] = bla.toByteArray()[0];
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yourself?

Comment: You have [`String(byte[]`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])), you just need to read the String to decode the bytes one by one to create that `byte[]`, try and come back if you can't.

Comment: The general process would be to `String::split` at the commas, write a convert `hexToDec()` function, subtract 128 from result, then cast to `byte`.  There is no such thing as a `uByte` in Java, that is why you would need to subtract 128 from result

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution with JAVA :

```
        String bytes="89,50,4e,47,0d,0a,1a,0a,00,00,00,0d,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,e4,08";
        String []tab=bytes.split(",");
        Integer []b = new Integer[tab.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tab.length ; i++){
             if(tab[i].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+"))
                 b[i]=Integer.parseInt(tab[i]);
             else
                 b[i]=Integer.parseInt(tab[i],16);


        }
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4e" at `b[i]=Byte.parseByte(tab[i]);`

Comment: i edited the answer , this will solve the problem :  `b[i]=Byte.parseByte(tab[i],16);`

Comment: Unfortunatelly this cause problem: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"89" Radix:16`

Comment: hmm java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"89" Radix:16 at `b[i]=Byte.parseByte(tab[i],16);` :/

Comment: so we have to test if the string is numeric or not , if it's not u parse it as hex , try it now :)  `if(tab[i].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+"))
             b[i]=Byte.parseByte(tab[i]);
         else
             b[i]=Byte.parseByte(tab[i],16);`

Comment: because e4 is 228 in Decimal , so u have to store in an Integer not in Byte , i updated the answer , i tested it , it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually parseByte doesn't seems to be a safe choice for your case because of [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6259307), so I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) to change it.

You can do:

```
String bytesAsStringWithCommas = "89,50,4e,47,0d,0a,1a,0a,00,00,00,0d,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,e4,08,06,00 ...";
String[] bytesStr = bytesAsStringWithCommas.split(",");
byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytesStr.length];
for (int j = 0; j < bytesStr.length; j++) {
    byteArray[j] = (byte) ((Character.digit(bytesStr[j].charAt(0), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(bytesStr[j].charAt(1), 16));
}
```

You should probably change your server code or client code to send data directly instead of using convoluted solutions like this one. Or you can also use Base64 encoding, which is going to be already better than your current solution.

Comment: `parseByte` requires 2nd argument 16.

Comment: You are perfectly right, thx. But I found that parseByte is not a very good choice actually (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String response ="89,50,47,00,00,00,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,08";

List<Byte> byteList = Arrays.stream(response.split(","))
   .map(Byte::parseByte)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

same as previous but with stream xD

but your example throws NumberFormatException on 4e, 0d and so on

Comment: OP wants a byte array, not a `List<Byte>`

Comment: eehm NumberFormatException xD

Comment: @JacobG. you can use .toArray(Byte[]::new) instead of .collect(Collectors.toList())

Comment: @sofarsoghood are you sure about dat string? Is it 100% valid?

Comment: @sofarsoghood have you tried response.getBytes() ? it returns byte[] from string

Comment: @Gleb Khrystenko reffering to this thread,yes :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859793/how-to-initialiaze-a-unsigned-byte-array-with-a-set-of-well-known-values-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (output is result of conversion):

```
    String input = "89,50,4e,47,0d,0a,1a,0a,00,00,00,0d,49,48,44,52,00,00,01,98,00,00,00,e4,08";

    String[] hex = input.split(",");
    char[] chars = new char[hex.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = (char) Integer.parseInt(hex[i], 16);
    }
    String output = new String(chars);
```